# Modal library similar to facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, modal-dialog

I need a good modal library that is similar to facebook. I wanna display a photo and some information on the side. Do you know of any? Most of them i saw just had pictures.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a modal library  https://github.com/mikesilvis/mikes-modal-library that i think is what you are looking for. It mimics facebook, and google plus and allows you to be able to have a picture of any size on the left, and then a comments area on the right.

Other cool features include the picture dynamically scales to the size of the window.

If you need any help implementing i would be more then happy to share!

Answer (score 0):

Those are called "lightbox", and there are too many to count. One example is this one: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

EDIT: If you want a more fully-featured solution, you want a modal window plugin of some kind, and build the template inside the window yourself.